# Цвет кнопки в Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, windows-10

Поменял палитру на кнопке - изменился цвет только у рамки - сама кнопка остается серой. Как дать на неё акцет? Свёрстанно через дизайнер.

```
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushOpen">
    <property name="sizePolicy">
     <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
      <horstretch>0</horstretch>
      <verstretch>0</verstretch>
     </sizepolicy>
    </property>
    <property name="minimumSize">
     <size>
      <width>0</width>
      <height>0</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="baseSize">
     <size>
      <width>0</width>
      <height>0</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="palette">
     <palette>
      <active>
       <colorrole role="WindowText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Button">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>32</red>
          <green>74</green>
          <blue>135</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Light">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>52</red>
          <green>101</green>
          <blue>164</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Midlight">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>52</red>
          <green>101</green>
          <blue>164</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Dark">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>32</red>
          <green>74</green>
          <blue>135</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Mid">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>52</red>
          <green>101</green>
          <blue>164</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Text">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ButtonText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>238</red>
          <green>238</green>
          <blue>236</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="PlaceholderText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="128">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
      </active>
      <inactive>
       <colorrole role="WindowText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Button">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>32</red>
          <green>74</green>
          <blue>135</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Light">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>52</red>
          <green>101</green>
          <blue>164</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Midlight">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>52</red>
          <green>101</green>
          <blue>164</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Dark">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>32</red>
          <green>74</green>
          <blue>135</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Mid">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>52</red>
          <green>101</green>
          <blue>164</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Text">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ButtonText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>238</red>
          <green>238</green>
          <blue>236</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="PlaceholderText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="128">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
      </inactive>
      <disabled>
       <colorrole role="WindowText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>32</red>
          <green>74</green>
          <blue>135</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Button">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>32</red>
          <green>74</green>
          <blue>135</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Light">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>52</red>
          <green>101</green>
          <blue>164</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Midlight">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>52</red>
          <green>101</green>
          <blue>164</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Dark">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>32</red>
          <green>74</green>
          <blue>135</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Mid">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>52</red>
          <green>101</green>
          <blue>164</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="Text">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>32</red>
          <green>74</green>
          <blue>135</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="ButtonText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="255">
          <red>32</red>
          <green>74</green>
          <blue>135</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
       <colorrole role="PlaceholderText">
        <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
         <color alpha="128">
          <red>0</red>
          <green>0</green>
          <blue>0</blue>
         </color>
        </brush>
       </colorrole>
      </disabled>
     </palette>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>12</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Открыть</string>
    </property>
    <property name="shortcut">
     <string>Ctrl+Return</string>
    </property>
    <property name="default">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
```

На линукс
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На виндовс
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На виндовс поправил цвет шрифта чтоб не сливалось, но саму кнопку покрасить не могу

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые стили, особенно системно зависимые Windows не могут отработать установку некоторых свойств.
Поэтому лучше использовать стили полностью выполненные средствами Qt. Это Fusion для Qt5.

Установите:

```
application.setStyle("Fusion");
```

Comment: емпин, для некоторых системных окон (ошибки сервисов, ошибки, балуны, нотификации) это не помогает

Comment: хотелось бы иметь нативные кнопки, только акцентировать както

Comment: @eri или применить стиль только к кнопке: button->setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"));, тогда будет выглядеть как в линуксе